# How to get Length from Array Model in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, typescript-typings

I am trying to get the length from Array interface. But getting error as:

`error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ModelSubSystems'.` In this case how to get the length. here is my TS code:

```
@Input() subsystems: ModelSubSystems;

resolve({ data: this.subsystems, totalCount: this.subsystems.length }); //error
```

here is my interfaces:

```
export interface ModelSubSystem {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    CreatedBy: string;
    CreatedDate: Date;
    UpdatedBy: string;
    UpdatedDate: Date;
}

export interface ModelSubSystems {
    subsystems: Array<ModelSubSystem>; //this is array!!
}
```

any one help me with correct approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want `this.subsystems.length`, or `this.subsystems.subsystems.length`?

Comment: @JeffBowman - I tried with declaring `@Input() subsystems: ModelSubSystems.subsystem;` but got the error as  `@Input() subsystems: ModelSubSystems.subsystem;`  But getting warning as `ModelSubSystems only refer to a type, but being used as a name space here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Input() subsystems: ModelSubSystems` this input variable will not have length because it is an `interface` with one property whose name is `subsystems` as well and is an array(the one you are trying to get length of).

The array property created in the interface can be accessed using `this.subsystems.subsystems` while the first `subsystem` here is you input of type `systemsystem` and the second one is the array in that interface.

If you want the `subsystems` input to be to be an array of `ModelSubSystem`,  instead of creating `ModelSubSystems` interface, directly declare this input as and array so that you can access its length:

```
@Input() subsystems: Array<ModelSubSystem>
```

Comment: I declared like this: `@Input() subsystems: ModelSubSystems.subsystem;`  But getting warning as `ModelSubSystems only refer to a type, but being used as a name space here`

Comment: But sad to see why my `ModelSubSystems` not helped here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the `this.subsystems` variable is initialised instead of only declared?

Typescript interface variables are `undefined` by default, so you will have to set them before they can be used / their methods can be called.

EDIT: as Jeff Bowman pointed out, what you actually need is `this.subsystems.subsystems.length`.

You could also add the `length` property to the interface, and have a class implement the desired behavior:

```
export interface IModelSubSystems {
  subsystems : Array<ModelSubSystem>;
  length : number;
}

export class ModelSubSystems implements IModelSubSystems {
  subsystems = new Array<ModelSubSystem>();
  get length() : number {
    return this.subsystems.length;
  }
}
```